# Browsers render in a strange way

Tags: user-interface, jsf-2, primefaces

First of all, let me give you some information. I'm developing a web application with this:

- Netbeans 7.2.1
- JSF-2 Mojarra 2.1.1
- Primefaces 3.4.2
- Chrome / Firefox

In one of the pages (actually, the index page) there is a panel (p:panel) that contains a data grid (p:dataGrid). Well, when the data grid has a few elements (more than two), the whole page renders in a very strange way. The best will be showing you a parcial screen shot.

[image: Before]

As you can see, two scroll bars appear (horizontally and vertically). I would think is a code problem if it weren't because by just accesing the developer's tools of the browser the page re-renders and the scroll bars disappear. This is result:

[image: After]

Both Chrome and Firefox browser have the same behaviour. I don't have any idea how to face this problem. I don't even know what kind of information I can give you because I don't know if the problem it's in my code, it's a Primefaces bug or what. 
Have you guys faced any similar problem anytime? I would like any suggestion from you.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT - This is a very simplified structure of the view:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west" size="66%">            
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <h:inputHidden .../>
        <h:inputHidden .../>
        <p:panel style="height: 95%" styleClass="transparent">   
            <p:dataGrid ...>
                <h:form>
                    <p:commandButton style="width: 100%" ...>
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener ... />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </h:form>
            </p:dataGrid> 
        </p:panel>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="33%">
        <p:panel style="height: 90%" styleClass="transparent">
        </p:panel>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit position="center" size="33%">
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <p:panel>
            <p:panel id="map"/>
        </p:panel>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="46%">
        <p:commandButton .../>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

Comment: What doctype are you using? In any case, an SSCCE would have been helpful in order to see the problem ourselves.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. I've tried with Transitional doctype and the problem remains the same. I'll try to edit the question adding an SSCCE, althought simplify the code will be a bit complicated becauses it's completely based on templates.

Comment: Hm, I don't recognize it. Are you using `<p:layout>`?

Comment: Yes. The layout is a bit complicated, but it works except for that issue.

Comment: It'll likely be a PrimeFaces bug.

Comment: I've add an SSCCE to my question. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: When I run this, I don't see the nested layout units at all. Is that indeed the problem? I've never really used `<p:layout>` though. I think you've better chance if you ask it on the PF forum.

Comment: Thank you, BalusC. The code I added to my question is a veeeery simplified version of the layout structure, so I may missed something. Anyway, I've replaced the `<p:layout>` elements for a construction based on `<p:panel>` and everything renders properly. Thanks again for your interest.